# Set tab title dynamically using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-easyui

I have a drop down and have three tabs,

Based on the value I receive I would like to set the title and id,

```
  <select class="easyui-combobox" name="state" style="width:200px;">
  <option value="DN">Denmark</option>  
  <option value="SG">Singapore</option>  
  <option value="JP">Japan</option>    
    </select>
```

If value is DN then

```
<div class="easyui-tabs" style="..." >
<div title="Denamrk"><table id="dg1">...</table</div>
<div title="DAN"><table id="dg2">...</table</div>
<div title="Danish Currency"><table id="dg3">...</table</div>
</div>
```

Or is it possible to use url and fetch data from server for tabs? Does tab or div has data option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try this out:-

**http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/fT5vt/2/**

## JS:-

```
var arrValues = {
    "DN": {
        0: "Denmark",
        1: "DAN",
        2: "Danish Currency"
    },
        "SG": {
        0: "Singapore",
        1: "SG",
        2: "SG Currency"
    },
        "JP": {
        0: "Japan",
        1: "JP",
        2: "JP Currency"
    }
};

function updateTabs() {
    var selectedOption = $('#dropdown').combobox('getValue');
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
         var tab = $('#tabs').tabs('getTab',i);
        $('#tabs').tabs('update', {
            tab: tab,
            options: {
                title: arrValues[selectedOption][i]
            }
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});
```

## HTML:-

```
<select id="dropdown" class="easyui-combobox" data-options="  
        onSelect: updateTabs" name="state" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="DN">Denmark</option>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
</select>
<div id="tabs" class="easyui-tabs" style="...">
    <div title="Denmark">
        <table id="dg1">...</table>
    </div>
    <div title="DAN">
        <table id="dg2">...</table>
    </div>
    <div title="Danish Currency">
        <table id="dg3">...</table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks indeed, looks great as well. +One.